# Sums Concerning Prime Gaps, Is This Worth Investigating More?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request, summation, solution-verification

I've stumbled upon an interesting find that I'm curious if it is already known or related items. Any thoughts welcome.

Define $n_k(t)$ to be an ordered index to the prime gaps such that $p_{n_k(t)+1}-p_{n_k(t)}=k$, so $n_2(1)=2$ and $n_4(2)=6$. Let $T_k$ be the largest possible $t$ for a given $k$, or infinity if there are infinitely many $t$ for a given $k$. Then the following sums converge for all possible $k$ values:

$$
S_k=\sum_{t=1}^{T_k}\frac{1}{n_k(t)}
$$

Sometimes I get excited about what most think is trivial, but I'm curious if this is more interesting than what I usually dig up. It's obvious for $k$ with $T_k$ finite, but it is unknown if $T_k$ are finite or infinite. All I can show is that the sums converge.

UPDATE:

Here is my proof of the convergence of $S_k$.

It starts by noticing that the following sum telescopes:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_k}\right)=\ln(p_{n+1})-\ln(2)
$$

Now, utilize the following bounds on the $n$-th prime number for $n\geq 6$:

$$
n\ln(n)<p_n<n\ln(n)\left(1+\frac{\ln\ln(n)}{\ln(n)}\right)
$$

to arrive at the following bounds:

$$
\ln(n+1)+\ln\ln(n+1)-\ln(2)<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_k}\right)<\ln(n+1)+\ln\ln(n+1)+\frac{\ln\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n+1)}-\ln(2)
$$

Now use the fact that the following limits hold true:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln(n+1)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=C_1
$$

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln\ln(n+1)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+1)\ln(k+1)}=C_2
$$

So if we subtract these sums in our bounds and take the limit, we'll arrive at

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\ln\left(\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_k}\right)-\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{(k+1)\ln(k+1)}\right]=C_1+C_2-\ln(2)
$$

Now, saw we have a function $f(k)>\epsilon>0$, so it can't get arbitrarily close to zero but it can get close to a given small number (or large, for that matter). Divide the terms of the sum by $f(k)$:

$$
-\frac{|C_1+C_2-\ln(2)|}{\epsilon}<
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\ln\left(\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_k}\right)}{f(k)}-\frac{1}{kf(k)}-\frac{1}{(k+1)\ln(k+1)f(k)}\right]<\frac{|C_1+C_2-\ln(2)|}{\epsilon}
$$

Now it is easy to see that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_k}\right)}{f(k)}
$$

converges if and only if

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{kf(k)}
$$

converges. Since $\ln(p_{k+1}/p_k)\sim \frac{g_k}{k\ln(k)}$, where $g_k$ is the $k$-th prime gap, we can say the same with the following sum:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{g_k}{k\ln(k+1)f(k)}
$$

converges if and only if

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{kf(k)}
$$

converges. Say $f(k)=g_k\ln(k+1)$, which clearly meets $f(k)>\epsilon>0$. So since

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{g_k}{k\ln(k+1)g_k\ln(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\ln^2(k+1)}
$$

converges, we can say

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k g_k\ln(k+1)}
$$

Now choose $f_2(k)=g_k^2$. Now since the following sum converges

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k g_k\ln(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{g_k}{k \ln(k+1)g_k^2}
$$

We now know that this sum also must converges

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k g_k^2}
$$

Now, this sum can be factored: each time $g_k=G$, we can group terms and factor out $\frac{1}{G^2}$. These factored sums are equivalent to $S_k$ at the top of this post. They must converge since the above sum converges.

Comment: No idea why someone would downvote this... how else is someone suppose to know if something they find is already known, especially if they have no math connections? This forum is one the few places I can ask these things and have someone say something back. Give me a break.

Comment: Not my downvote, but one way to improve the question would be to explain why these sums converge. And could you clarify what you mean when you say that it is unknown if these sums are finite or infinite? You just wrote that they converge, so that means they are finite.

Comment: Also, your description of $n_k(t)$ could be clearer. It took me a while to make sure I understood it correctly. Not the end of the world, but definitely room for improvement.

Comment: I mean it is unknown if $T_k$ is finite or infinite. I'll add the reasoning of why they converge sometime in the near future. Thanks for the feedback @Servaes

Comment: I agree with @Servaes, the definition of $n_k(t)$ is hard to parse. Also, the only question here (in the title) is not really mathematical. It's asking for advice.

Comment: @Barry Cipra do you know of a platform for asking for "mathematical" advice? Apparently I joined the wrong community...

Comment: @Samuel, you might try rewriting your question here as a reference request, summarizing what you've found (with an example or two showing the first few terms of an $S_k$, to help the reader understand your definition of the $n_k(t)$'s), and asking if this is already known.  Offhand it strikes me as original, and therefore potentially interesting, and even if it isn't I would encourage you to continue investigating it. Either way, kudos for coming up with it yourself.

Comment: @Servaes, could you take a look at my answer, to see if my understanding of the $n_k(t)$'s corresponds to yours?

Comment: @BarryCipra thanks for the point towards reference request. I'm relatively new to the platform and a learning novice. It helps to have some direction on how to get better responses. Cheers

Comment: @Samuel, thank you for adding your proof. I think it has a mistake, though. In asserting the inequality when you divide the terms of the series by $f(k)$, it looks like you're assuming all the terms of the series are positive. But the first two terms (with $k=1$ and $2$), at least, are *negative*. If the altered sum (with $f(k)$ added to the denominators) is a mix of positive and negative terms, you may not be able to say what you want to say about the convergence of its various parts.

Comment: @BarryCipra That's why I say less than the absolute value of the constants, but what I also need to say is that it is greater than the constants divided by $\epsilon$ as well.

Comment: @BarryCipra I added a lower bound to that spot in the proof where I divide by $f(k)$ to show that it is bounded on both sides.

Comment: @BarryCipra I think I'm realizing more of what you talked about. I'm currently thinking of a way around it, perhaps restraining $f(k)$ to be greater than or equal to $1$ and showing the absolute value of the orginal terms of the sum are less than 1?

Comment: @BarryCipra Yeah, I think it would need to be shown that the negative values taken by themselves converge as well as the positive values taken by themselves converge in the original sum to show what I'm trying to show. Thanks for your input. Cheers

Comment: @Servaes, you might open a new question (with a link to this one). You have a well defined infinite series that converges (to $C_1+C_2-\ln(2)$). Is the convergence absolute or merely conditional? This might even be a MathOverflow question.  (Incidentally, I recognize $C_1$ as Euler's constant, but I'm not familiar with $C_2$ or its approximate value.)

Comment: @BarryCipra I posted a follow up here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221621/absolute-or-conditional-convergence-of-series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have parsed the OP's definition of $n_k(t)$ correctly, they are taking the reciprocals of the positive integers $n$ and placing $1/n$ into a sum $S_k$ if $p_{n+1}-p_n=k$, i.e., if there's a gap of size $k$ after the $n$th prime. Thus $S_1=1$ is a finite sum (since $2$ is the only even prime and $3-2=1$), while

$$\begin{align}
S_2&={1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over5}+{1\over7}+{1\over10}+{1\over13}+{1\over17}+{1\over20}+\cdots\\
S_4&={1\over4}+{1\over6}+{1\over8}+{1\over12}+{1\over14}+{1\over19}+\cdots\\
S_6&={1\over9}+{1\over11}+{1\over15}+{1\over16}+{1\over18}+\cdots
\end{align}$$

are, according to the Twin Prime Conjecture and its generalization, [de Polignac's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture), presumably all infinite sums. What I've shown here places each reciprocal from $1/2$ to $1/20$ into its appropriate sum; the next reciprocal, $1/21$, will go into $S_6$ since the $21$st prime is $73$ and it has a gap of size $6$ to the next prime, $79$. More terms for $S_2$, $S_4$, and $S_6$ can be found at [A029707](https://oeis.org/A029707), [A029709](https://oeis.org/A029709), and [A320701](https://oeis.org/A320701), respectively.  The first term in $S_8$ is $1/24$, since $p_{25}-p_{24}=97-89=8$.  In general, the opening term for $S_{2m}$ is the $m$th term at [A038664](https://oeis.org/A038664), although it's still only conjectural (I think) that a gap of each even size occurs somewhere amongst the primes (i.e., de Polignac's Conjecture could conceivably be *very* wrong).

Note that $S_1+S_2+S_4+S_6+S_8+\cdots$ is just a rearrangement of the harmonic series, hence divergent. The OP claims to have proved that each $S_k$ by itself is convergent. I'd sort of like to see the proof. In particular, $S_2$ provides an upper bound on Brun's sum, since it's summing the reciprocals of the *indices* of the twin primes rather than the twin primes themselves. (More precisely, it sums the reciprocal of the index of the *first* prime in each twin-prime pair; Brun's sum sums the reciprocals of both primes in each pair, i.e.,

$$B=\left({1\over3}+{1\over5}\right)+\left({1\over5}+{1\over7}\right)+\left({1\over11}+{1\over13}\right)+\left({1\over17}+{1\over19}\right)+\cdots$$

But ${1\over2}\lt{1\over3}+{1\over5}$ and ${1\over3}\lt{1\over5}+{1\over7}$ look like the only terms for which the comparison inequality points the "wrong" way; this is surely easy to prove.) Explicit upper bounds for Brun's sum are known, but they're not easy to come by, so if the OP's proof that $S_2$ converges includes an explicit upper bound for it, that would be interesting.

I am unaware of any literature on the sums that the OP is considering, but I'm far from expert in the area. I would guess, for example, that $S_{2m}\to0$ as $m\to\infty$, but it's not clear (to me) that that's necessarily the case; it'd be interesting, I think, to see some provable asymptotics for the sums.

Comment: Your interpretation of $n_k(t)$ is the same as mine. Your thoughts on the matter are roughly the same as mine. I'll refrain from upvoting until OP has clarified what the $n_k(t)$ are, and why they believe the $S_k$ all converge.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning [de Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture), that $T_k$ is infinite for every even positive integer $k$.

Comment: @Servaes, thanks for your replies. I've added mention of de Polignac.

Comment: @Barry Cipra Thanks for the response. I will update with a proof. Your interpretation of the $n_k(t)$ is correct. Bruns sum I'll have to look at more. Thanks for the reference. Cheers

Comment: @BarryCipra I've updated my post with the proof.