# Absolute or Conditional Convergence of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, reference-request, prime-numbers

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218459/sums-concerning-prime-gaps-is-this-worth-investigating-more?noredirect=1#comment8763636_4218459) I show that following sum is convergent where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime number:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\ln\left(\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_{k}}\right)-\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{(k+1)\ln(k+1)}\right] = C<\infty
$$

Is the series absolutely convergent or just conditionally? I know the following related sum is absolutely convergent because all the terms are greater than $0$:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\ln\left(\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_{k}}\right)-\frac{p_{k+1}-p_k}{p_k}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{p_{k+1}-p_k}{p_k}\right)^2\right] = B<\infty
$$

It is convergent because the series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ and $p_{k+1}<p_k+p_k^{.525}$.

Back to the top sum, when prime gaps are bigger relative to the $k$-th prime, the addends are positive and when they are smaller relative tot he $k$-prime, the terms are negative. There seems to be more negative terms than positive terms but the range of absolute values seem to be the same for either case. For twin-primes the addends are always greater than $-\frac{1}{k}$ but trail close to it.

I have my doubts that it is absolutely convergent. I think the negative end will easily go to infinity.

UPDATE:

If

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|f(k)-g(k)|=C_1<\infty
$$

and

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g(k)-h(k)|=C_2<\infty
$$

Then

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|f(k)-h(k)|=C_3<\infty
$$

So the question is equivalent to asking if the following sum is absolutely convergent or not:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{p_{k+1}-p_k}{p_k}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{p_{k+1}-p_k}{p_k}\right)^2-\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{(k+1)\ln(k+1)}\right] = A<\infty
$$

Interesting enough, one can replace the last term of the sum with the reciprocal of the $k$-th prime and get the following:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{p_{k+1}-p_k-1}{p_k}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{p_{k+1}-p_k}{p_k}\right)^2-\frac{1}{k}\right] = A_2<\infty
$$

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that. I mean the gap is less than that.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. The exponent $.525$ seems like a funny number though. Is there a standard reference for that inequality? Is $p_k+p_k^{1/2}$ not a correct upper bound?

Comment: Yes, it is a silly number. But $.5$ is too small for current literature. That bound would be stronger than the Riemann Hypothesis. I can add a reference later.

Comment: @BarryCipra see this post for a culmination of what I've been working on so far the past few weeks related to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4233655/533774