# Reference Request: Generalized Limit Definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, limits, number-theory, reference-request

I've been working on a framework for dealing with large and small sets. A large set of positive integers is one which the sum of the reciprocals of the members of the set diverges and a small set  of positive integers is one which the sum of the reciprocals of the members of the set converges, and may be a finite set.

As I was building this out, I noticed the following construction that seems to be a rather good generalization of the limit concept.

Let $f(n)$ be any function that maps integers to reals. We say $f(n)$ converges **almost everywhere** to $L$ if we can find a large set $S=\{s_1,s_2,s_3,...\}$ with $s_k<s_{k+1}$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{s_n:|f(n)-L|<\epsilon\}$ is large and the set $\{s_n:|f(n)-L|\geq\epsilon\}$ is small. Notice that $f(n)$ converges to $L$ if and only if $\{s_n:|f(n)-L|\geq\epsilon\}$ is finite for all $\epsilon>0$ (a subclass of small).

Has anyone seen similar constructions that I can read up on and perhaps use in my framework?

It is easy to show that if the following sum converges with $\{s_n\}$ being large, then $f(n)$ converges almost everywhere to $L$:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|f(n)-L|}{s_n}
$$

This is handy for dealing with sets like the primes. In fact, if we denote $f(n)$ converging almost everywhere to $L$ as

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)\doteq L
$$

Then one can show that

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{p_{n+1}-p_n}\doteq 0
$$

which demonstrates that twin primes, cousin primes, etc, all form small sets and at the same time that primes get arbitrarily farther apart.

Another interesting limit is the following for any real $0\leq x<1$

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_{n+1}^x-p^x_n\doteq 0
$$

UPDATE: For anyone reading through the comments and getting confused with a supposed counter example, the function $f(n)$ equaling $1$ if $n$ is composite and $0$ if $n$ is prime does not converge to $0$ under this construction. Indeed, it is because the primes are a large set that the function actually converges to $1$. The goal is to find a large set $S$ such that $\{s_n:|f(n)-L|\geq\epsilon\}$ is small. If one chooses $L=0$, this set is not small when $S$ is the primes. However, it is small when one chooses $L=1$ because the sequence $p_{p_n}$ forms a small set of integers.

Update 2:

To show that the reciprocal of the prime gaps converges to $0$ almost everywhere, one shows that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_{p_n}}
$$

Converges if and only if

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_{n}G(n)}
$$

Converges, where $G(n)=M(n)-m(n)$ where $M(n)$ is the smallest prime greater than $n$ and $m(n)$ is the largest prime less than $n$.

Comment: Somewhat similar to your 3rd paragraph are, I think, some constructions in Chapter 1 of Thomson's book [**Real Functions**](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540160588). See also the first 2 or 3 pages of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-30/issue-1/On-generalizations-of-Fletts-Theorem/rae/1122482117.full) for an overview, if Thomson's book isn't available to you.

Comment: Thanks @DaveL.Renfro for the references. Local systems look interesting and it seems I may need to do some reading up on them to understand them more. I've got a good research library nearby that probably has that book that I can rent or they can loan it probably. Thanks alot!

Comment: I see one quirk in your definitions, which I'll illustrate with an example. Define $f$ by $f(n)=1$ if $n$ is composite and $f(n)=0$ if $n$ is prime.  Then $f(n)$ converges almost everywhere to $0$ because the set of primes is a large set (the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges). But at the same time, $f(n)$ converges almost everywhere to $1$ because the set of composite numbers is also large. It seems to me it might make more sense to define "almost everywhere" convergence to mean there's some *small* set which, once excluded, leaves a large set on which the function converges.

Comment: @BarryCipra I'm not following you. By my definition of almost everywhere your $f(n)$ cannot converge almost everywhere to $0$. The set of primes would not be enough. The set outside of the $0$ would be a large set, so it wouldn't satisfy the conditions for almost convergent. One can show that your function does converge almost everywhere to 1 since you can choose the primes as a large set and the $p_{p_n}$ values would converge, creating a small set. Perhaps I'm missing something from what you said?

Comment: @BarryCibra I think where you got it a little wrong was that it isn't enough for $\{s_n:|f(n)-L|<\epsilon\}$ to be large. An additional requirement is that the left over in $\{s_n:|f(n)-L|\geq\epsilon\}$ has to be small. So in the case of your function, if you try to construct it for almost convergent to $0$, the left over set is large.

Comment: I don't know why this (what I'm about to bring up) didn't occur to me earlier, as I have probably over 100 papers on the topic (most of which I've glanced over and briefly summarized or excerpted from in my personal-use bibliography), but what you **really want to look at** is [statistical convergence of sequences](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22statistical+convergence%22+sequence&filter=0) and [ideal convergence in sequences](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ideal+convergence%22+sequence&filter=0) **(continued)**

Comment: and [various generalizations involving both notions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ideal+convergence%22+%22statistical+convergence%22+sequence&filter=0). Incidentally, some of MSE's [Martin Sleziak](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak) research involves these notions (e.g. [this paper is a useful overview](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/papers/iconvtalk.pdf) and **(continued)**

Comment: [this paper introduces a rather far-reaching generalization of some of this stuff](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-36/issue-1/%E2%84%91%E1%B4%B7-convergence/rae/1300108092.full)), so you may want to contact him about where would be a good place to begin if you want to look into these topics.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro You are awesome! This is exactly what I constructed except your references are a lot  more generalized. Really interesting.

Comment: How do you show that $1/(p_{n+1}-p_n)\to 0$ a.e.?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I added a short blurb on that