# Help Refining Generalization of Continuous Limit

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

In a continuation of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4233655/reference-request-generalized-limit-definition), I'm looking at extending this to a similar continuous limit process instead of just being a discrete case.

I'm starting with a continuous analogy to large and small. I'll say a function $g(x)$ is large on $\Omega$ if $\int_\Omega g(x)dx=\infty$ and is small on $\Omega$ if $\int_\Omega g(x)dx=C<\infty$.

This is where I'm not sure how to define it. What I currently have is this. We say $f(x)$ converges almost everywhere to $L$ if we can find a function $g(x)$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ $g(x)$ is large on $\Omega_<=\{I:|f(x)-L|<\epsilon \forall x\in I\}$ and $g(x)$ is small on $\Omega_{\geq}=\{I:|f(x)-L|\geq\epsilon \forall x\in I\}$.

Can this definition be improved upon? It feels a little clunky.

Part of the end result of this is that if

$$
\int_\Omega g(x)dx=\infty
$$

and

$$
\int_\Omega |f(x)-L|g(x)dx=C<\infty
$$

Then one can say $f(x)$ converges almost everywhere to $L$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm going about it slightly off.

How about this:

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbf{R}$ and $g(x)$ be large on $\Omega$. Let $\Omega_\epsilon\subset\Omega$ be such that $|f(x)-L|\geq\epsilon$ for all $x\in\Omega_\epsilon$ and let $\Omega_\epsilon^{'}\subset\Omega$ be such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in\Omega_\epsilon^{'}$ where $\Omega_\epsilon^{'}\bigcup\Omega_\epsilon=\Omega$. We say $f(x)$ is $(\Omega, g)$-convergent to $L$ if $g(x)$ is small on $\Omega_\epsilon$.

This captures both the discrete and continuous cases.